# Integrate Flurry SDK and plugin for Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, flurry, flurry-analytics

I want to add Flurry SDK to my project, but I have a question.

If you go to Flurry's GitHub, if you want to use the push function, it tells you to edit "AndroidManifest.

After installing the Firebase SDK, the "AndroidManifest.xml" file is installed. Delete this file and rename the file "Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest_Flurry-template.xml" provided by Flurry to "AndroidManifest.xml". Guernsey?

Or I want to know if it is necessary to copy and paste only meta-data in "Flurry AndroidManifest_Flurry-template.xml" to "AndroidManifest.xml" installed when installing Firebase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the merge as the docs also mentioned, then you need to remove the Firebase's part. Keeping those parts will introduce push conflict between Flurry Push and Firebase Messaging.

Yes, you can merge your settings in the same file "AndroidManifest.xml" whenever they won't have any conflict.

Comment: I tried to delete the "AndroidManifest.xml" file generated by Firebase, but even if I delete it, it is created again.
Could you please tell me what to do?

Comment: Firebase generates new "AndroidManifest.xml" only during the setup. It should not auto-replace user's own one. Otherwise it should be a bug from there.
BTW, in order to use Flurry Push, you don't need to finish the whole steps as Firebase asks. Please check our guide at https://github.com/flurry/unity-flurry-sdk:
"Follow Set up a Firebase Cloud Messaging client app with Unity. Complete to the 5th step for importing Firebase SDK. There should be a file google-services.json in your project's Android folder now. You do not need to provide any setup codes here."

Comment: I do not understand the part of setting "AndroidManifest.xml" after reading the guide and proceeding to step 5 of Firebase
I'm not good at interpreting English, but I've tried retrying in various ways because it's a difference in interpretation, but even if I use the push from Flurry's dashboard, there is no response from my phone.
I'm sorry, but can you give me a little more detail?